# jQuery hover animation: Can't animate opacity and background position simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a navigation element so that when the mouse hovers over the element, it becomes fully opaque (from 30% opacity), and the background image moves up by 10px. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#topnav li')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {'background-position-y': '28px'},
        {opacity: 1},
        {duration:100})
    })
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate(
        {'background-position-y': '38px'},
        {opacity: 0.3},  
        {duration:100})
    })
});
</script>
```

However, only the first animation listed actually plays. As written, the background position animates but the opacity does not. If I switch the opacity and background-position animations, then the opacity animates, but the background position does not. I'm not very good with jQuery, but from what I've read, it seems like this should work. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct form of arguments for animating multiple properties.  All properties belong in the object that is passed as the first argument.  This is quite clear in the [doc for jQuery `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#topnav li')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).animate(
        {'background-position-y': '28px', opacity: 1},
        {duration:100})
    });
.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop(true).animate(
        {'background-position-y': '38px', opacity: 0.3},
        {duration:100})
    });
});
</script>
```

FYI, you also probably want `.stop(true)` to remove the previous animation from the queue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely missed the extra curly brackets. Guess it's what I get for trying to code at 11:30 at night on a weekday. -_-

Comment: @user1234492 - as a new user on StackOverflow, do you realize that if you get a good answer to your question, you should mark it as the best answer by click on the checkmark to the left of the answer?  This not only indicates to other readers which answer worked for you, but also earns some reputation points for both you and the person who provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), the `property` is a map of CSS properties and `duration` is the second parameter.

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    'background-position-y': '28px',
    'opacity': 1
}, 100)
```

Comment: Duration can be passed in a map for the second argument if desired.  In the jQuery doc, this is the "second form" of `.animate()`.